# How to prevent other user from modifying grouped object that I created in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

So I have a logo which is grouped objects, what I am trying to do is allow other users to open the .ai file and copy the logo and use it, but not allow them to ungroup it or make any changes in each layer.

I guess locking is not the way to go, will applying a clip mask help as a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Must it remain as a vector? if not, just export it as a  high res transparent background PNG (for example)

Comment: right, it needs to remain as a vector. it has to be a .ai file instead of PNG or other export format. hmm... not sure if this can be achieved in illustrator.

Comment: You can not protect digital content. If it can be viewed it can be edited. You can downgrade quality in which case editing gives less quality. 100 of millions have been spent on trying to make copy protection, but they all fail because in order to use you have to give end user a viable copy, and thus he can copy it. No way around this unless you own the hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Any native, vector, .ai file can be edited in Illustrator.

You can do things such as locking or grouping objects and layers, but any AI user that knows how to use AI can get around that as easily as you implement it.

**Short of rasterizing content, you can't prevent editing.**

You can make editing *difficult* in some cases by expanding and flattening everything. However, that still doesn't prevent editing.